# Attempting to improve Math.random() in browser

Tags: javascript, security, encryption, cryptography

Looking for a little expert advice on this one, my knowledge of cryptography is cursory at best.

I'm wondering if this is a viable solution for generating cryptographically secure random numbers. More specifically I'm wondering if using Math.abs() or Math.sin() to clamp the number will reduce the randomness of the number I get from crypto.getRandomValues so much that it is no longer useful for encryption.

---

```js
if(window.crypto && window.crypto.getRandomValues) {

 Math.random = () => {

   var array = new Uint32Array(1)

   window.crypto.getRandomValues(array)

   return Math.abs(Math.sin(array[0]))

 }

}

console.log(Math.random())
```

jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/mg7ftm7w/

note: I've only tested this snippet in Chrome. I don't think the window.crypto object is present in IE.

Comment: What is it you're trying to achieve by "clamping" the number? Is your goal uniform randomness? You won't get that by taking the `sin` of a uniform random variable. `|sin(x)|` is greater than `0.707` over 50% of the time. You're not reducing entropy, but you are changing the distribution to be non-uniform.

Comment: Here is an update to your JSFiddle that demonstrates the distribution you have: https://jsfiddle.net/mg7ftm7w/2/ . You haven't lost any randomness, but you're going to get many more numbers close to `1` than you will close to `0`.

Comment: @Paulpro The native implementation of Math.random returns numbers between 0 and 1. Just trying to stay consistent to avoid breaking things.

Comment: So you do want uniform randomness? getRandomValues returns all possible values uniformly at random so you just need to divide by the max UInt32 + 1: `return array[0]/(2**32)`. JSFiddle https://jsfiddle.net/mg7ftm7w/4/

Comment: @Paulpro Thanks, that's great. I didn't benchmark but I'm sure it's some magnitude faster as well.